# Get_the_author doesn't return author name

Tags: php, posts, author, single

I insert author box below my post and use get_the_author to return author name but it doesn't working. It also doesn't working with Search post by author. Hope everyone give me solution, thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this code inside a proper Loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Echo it out... `<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>`

Answer (score 6):

Though `echoing` worked for the OP, the issue could be related to setting up the post manually, as was in my case. Here is the code:

```
$post = get_post();
setup_postdata($post);    // setting up the post manually

// Then you can fetch/echo the author name
var $authorName = get_the_author(); 
var $content    = get_the_content();   // This works too
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, any WP function beginning with `get_` will return the result rather than echoing it. There's usually a corresponding function - in this case it's `the_author()` - which will echo it.